# Transparency in Tkinter PhotoImage

Tags: python, tkinter

In my simple game I'm creating I currently have placeholder rectangle objects as graphics. I'm trying to replace them with sprites, but as I understand it Tkinter doesn't have support for PNGs or alpha transparency. I am using Python 3.3, which doesn't work with PIL (and since it is a school project, I am solely trying to use Tkinter as the only external library). Is there a way to use the alpha channel with the supported file formats so that I can have multiple layers of tiles? I just want to filter out the white pixels.

Comment: I just have the feeling that the color #FF00FF could be transparent or maybe you can set a transparent color. By the way I found a Bitmap image that has Mask data - could be it

Comment: Do you know how to implement this?

Comment: Ah, I remember.. I think you can try to set only the colorful pixels and the other pixels should be transparent. I f that doesn not work, look at Tkinter.BitmapImage.

Answer (score 2):

To make the white pixels transparent (I am assuming that white means #ffffff) you could use this function below or something like it.  This does not require PIL.  It has worked for me for pngs, but also will work for gif.

- First, make a new blank image the same size as your image.
- Second, copy pixel by pixel to the new image (unless the pixel is white).
- Set your original image to the new image.

Here is an example of the function being used:

```
from tkinter import *


def makeTransparent(img, colorToMakeTransparentInHexFormat):
    newPhotoImage = PhotoImage(width=img.width(), height=img.height())
    for x in range(img.width()):
        for y in range(img.height()):
            rgb = '#%02x%02x%02x' % img.get(x, y)
            if rgb != colorToMakeTransparentInHexFormat:
                newPhotoImage.put(rgb, (x, y))
    return newPhotoImage


root = Tk()
mycanvas = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200,bg="orange")
mycanvas.pack()

myphotoImage = PhotoImage(file="whitecar.gif")
#set your image to the image returned by the function
myphotoImage = makeTransparent(myphotoImage, "#ffffff")
canvasImage = mycanvas.create_image(100, 100, image=myphotoImage, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is an example of a white car with a white background:

[image: car with white background]

Here is an example of that car on the canvas using the example program:

[image: car on canvas with orange background]

So I hope I have answered your question.

- I did not use PIL.  nothing but the tkinter module.
- I only used gif, not png as you asked.
- Wherever white is, will now be transparent.

---

###### Note:

For whatever reason, processing transparency multiple times with the above function can result in viewing errors in tkinter.  Below is a way to remove multiple colors by using a color switching function:
Here is a car:

[image: red car with grey background]

Here is another function to switch colors, which can be implemented before making a color transparent.

```
def switchColors(img, currentColor,futureColor):
    newPhotoImage = PhotoImage(width=img.width(), height=img.height())
    for x in range(img.width()):
        for y in range(img.height()):
            rgb = '#%02x%02x%02x' % img.get(x, y)
            if rgb == currentColor:
                newPhotoImage.put(futureColor, (x, y))
            else:
                newPhotoImage.put(rgb, (x, y))
    return newPhotoImage
```

Here it is in use

```
root = Tk()
mycanvas = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200,bg="orange")
mycanvas.pack()

myphotoImage = PhotoImage(file="car.png")

myphotoImage = switchColors(myphotoImage,"#db0000","#ffffff") #switch red to white
myphotoImage = switchColors(myphotoImage,"#d9d9d9","#ffffff") #switch greybackground to white
myphotoImage = switchColors(myphotoImage,"#6d6d6d","#ffffff") #switch windshield grey to white
myphotoImage = makeTransparent(myphotoImage,"#ffffff") #make white transparent

canvasImage = mycanvas.create_image(100, 100, image=myphotoImage, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

And here is the result of that process:

[image: car with 2 greys and red removed]

Here is a reference to a similar problem:
[How to rotate an image on a canvas without using PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248426/how-to-rotate-an-image-on-a-canvas-without-using-pil)

Comment: What if the image has some other color in between that has to be made transparent?

Comment: Hmm, I guess you could run this function a second time.  Run it once to remove white for example, then run it again to remove a second color.  I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: @CoolCloud.  Actually for reasons I haven't yet figured out, it does not wok properly wihen I run it sequentially.  However, I was able to remove 2 colors by writing a second function, `switchColors`.  I switched red out for white, then made white transparent, effectively removing 2 colors, both red and white.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use an image with transparency. I understand your wish to avoid use of PIL, but the following code works and demonstrates that Tkinter will support formats with transparency.

```py
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas
import PIL
root = Tk() 
tkimg = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage('cat1-a.gif')
canvas = Canvas(root, height=600, width=600)
canvas.grid()
def stamp(event):
    canvas.create_image(event.x, event.y, image=tkimg)
canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', stamp)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: three create_image() calls demonstrate transparency]

Comment: When having trouble with ImageTk under Linux (no module _imagingtk), refer to this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156484/how-do-i-install-python-imaging-library-pil

Comment: Your answer might not quite fit the question but it has relevance and a nice example potentially helping people finding themselves here with a similar question. Add `from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas` and `import PIL` at the top and `root.mainloop()` at the bottom to run.

Comment: Thanks @valid, I added that to the code for future readers' convenience and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to use PIL with Python 3 using non-official versions of PIL
Go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ to download it.